# How to refresh tokens for Twilio Conversations API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I following the documentation here to create a token for the Conversation API.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/quickstart?code-sample=code-fetch-your-new-conversation&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#configure-the-conversations-demo-application-using-codesandboxio

```
twilio token:chat --identity testPineapple --chat-service-sid ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --profile project-danger
```

This works for me, but these tokens expire after a given time. How do you refresh this token for a Conversation? I am creating these tokens from node.js.

Answer (score -1):

On the Twilio Official [Doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/access-token-lifecycle)

Once you generate a token and pass it to the client, Client can subscribe to
`tokenAboutToExpire` events which is fired **3 minute before** your token is expired

```
client.on('tokenAboutToExpire', function() {  
   // Same way you generated the token for the first time
   fetchToken(function(updatedToken) {
     chatClient.updateToken(updatedToken);
   });
});
```

Comment: Also here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/best-practices-sdk-clients#the-jwt-jwe-token-lifecycle

Comment: Thank you the help! How do I create a new token for this existing Conversation?

Comment: The token was generated from node.js, but I want to update the token from the iOS SDK.

Comment: @Berry Blue Did you find any solution?